# I wish to make a smooth motion like hips of belly dance

Tags: bezier-curves, keyframes

I have moved the hip joint on a character, from center position then to a few edges of a circle, but dont know if I can smoothen the motion rather than the way it looks now which is trianglar.

I would rather make the motion as my diagram suggests. but I think you can use curve paths etc, not sure how. but more to simplicity of creation extra objects, is it possible to magically make blender fill in the gaps from where KF2-KF3 etc[image: Keyframes on circle]

Object = Hip on the RIG
KF1-KF6 = Locations blender has already been setup with.

my objective would be to auto create the filling keyframes inbetween KF2-KF3 and KF3-KF4 etc, maybe like subframes

I dont want to overload blender with a tonne of Keyframes... but to automate with some trick that keeps blender clean would help my animating process

thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 1):

> Note 1: **It's not bad to have a lot of keyframes!** You can easily get used to a key on every frame and grabbing large blocks of keyed animation. When animating over motion-captured or simulated data this is a common occurence. The graph editor should be **intuitive**, but not clean/tidy!
>
> Note 2: A belly dancer's hips would likely move in an ∞ like shape or an ellipsoid, not in a circle (a very unnatural shape for movement).

1. A simple **sin** and **cos** function can be overlayed if the circular motion is happening on 2 axes only. Select the graphs, add a modifier each (sin and cosine), choose additive for both and set their *phase multiplier* to the same value. (You can type `1/pi` in the *phase multiplier* field.)
   [image]
   If you want the movement on certain frames use the *Restrict Frame Range* functionality of the modifiers or keyframe the *Influence*.
   When you want to edit the movement further you'll have to **[bake](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/actions.html#bake-action)** the action.
2. Another method is simply setting good keyframes and using interpolation to your advantage. Keying the four position (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0) and (0, 1) gives us this awkward motion.
   [image]
   To fix this, make the extremes the start and end of the cycle and remove the breakdowns of the curve. Or rotation the Auto Clamped keys which prevent a smooth movement.
   [image]

Comment: The sine and cosine for x and y, have you actually moved the object around to begin or has the sine done the job. I.e. kf1 to kf2

Comment: @ToxsickcitY In method #1 the movement is fully generated. In method two I started with the four handkeyed frames.